# SQL: Find Customer who has account in Lonsdale but not in Robson

Tags: sql

I need to find the customerIDs of customers who have an account in
the Lonsdale branch but don't have one in Robson.

**Bank Schemata:**

```
Customer = {customerID, firstName, lastName, birthDate, income}
Account = {accNumber, type, balance, rate, branchName}
    ▪ branchName is a foreign key referencing Branch
Owns = {customerID, accNumber}
    ▪ customerID and accNumber are foreign keys referencing Customer and Account
```

The **correct** way doing so is like this:

```
SELECT O1.customerID
FROM Owns O1, Account A1
WHERE A1.accNumber = O1.accNumber AND
A1.branchName = 'Lonsdale'
EXCEPT
SELECT O2.customerID
FROM Owns O2, Account A2
WHERE A2.accNumber = O2.accNumber AND
A2.branchName = 'Robson'
```

But, The **incorrect** query is like this:

```
SELECT O1.customerID
FROM Owns O1, Account A1, Owns O2, Account A2
WHERE O1.customerID = O2.customerID AND
O1.accNumber = A1.accNumber AND
O2.accNumber = A2.accNumber AND
A1.branchName = 'Lonsdale' AND
A2.branchName <> 'Robson
```

The query actually returns who own any account that isn't the Robson branch. My question is: Why this query is not working? (regardless the running time). what is actually going on in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is due to result sets.

The first query gets a result set for Lonsdale accounts, gets another result set for Robson accounts, and **returns a result set where there are records in the first result set and not in the second**.

The second query gets a single result set but the comparison is being done on a single row, not on separate result sets. This means it will **find all rows that have a branch name of Lonsdale and a branch name not equal to Robson**. For the same record. The branch name of Lonsdale essentially cancels out the not equal to Robson.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: If a customer has a Lonsdale account, it will get a row of its ID and Lonsdale twice in a row. that automatically satisfy A1.branchName = 'Lonsdale' AND A2.branchName <> 'Robson' I understand now

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some sort of aggregation by customer if you want to answer this question.  Consider the following query:

```
SELECT
    o.customerID
FROM owns o
INNER JOIN Account a
    ON o.accNumber = a.accNumber
GROUP BY
    o.customerID
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.branchName = 'Lonsdale' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.branchName = 'Robson'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

This query works by tallying, for each customer, the number of times an account in Lonsdale or Robson appears.  The `HAVING` clause then asserts that Lonsdale appears at least once and Robson appears zero times.

The reason why your second approach does not work is that we can't both count and not count a single record.